# Select text on IScroll when press control key?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iscroll

I'm using IScroll on my website.

It's works very great. but, I can't select any text in page with mouse cursor.

I want to select text in IScroll with mouse cursor , when holding Control [`Ctrl`] key.

Is it possible or not ? If possible please give me the code.

Comment: I have the exact same issue using version 4.2.5. It's seems like all interactions (events) are blocked.